# What are the differences between Steam and GOG versions of Microïds' Dracula games?

Tags: version-differences, dracula-series

[Steam releases of the three Microïds' Dracula games](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price_ASC&term=dracula&developer=Microids) have received extremely poor user reviews. The users complain about cut content, bugs not present in the original physical release and modified gameplay, suggesting that the Steam versions are based on [mobile ports](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Anuman).

[The GOG versions](https://www.gog.com/game/dracula_trilogy) ("Dracula Trilogy" contains all "The Resurrection", "The Last Sanctuary" and "The Path of the Dragon") whereas are well received, averaging a user rating of four stars of five (please note that GOG reviews aren't tied to game ownership). Is the trilogy served on GOG in its native PC form?

Comment: Based on my experience with GOG games, I have RCT 1 and 2, they seem to be the exact same game as they were when originally released, just ported to work for newer systems. Now, both of those games include all of the expansion packs that werent released with the original versions, but other than that, game play and graphics have been the exact same.

Comment: In general, always look for older games on gog first. Gog makes an effort to bring you the game in its best possible version ready to play. The steam version is usually just put there by the publisher without any modification. An egregious example is Freespace 2, which suffers poor reviews on Steam due to the steam version being horribly bugged on newer systems.

Comment: According to ['Games not available on Steam' GOGmix](https://www.gog.com/mix/games_not_available_on_steam), the games on Steam are based on the iOS version.